# Request data whose fields value are superior to n

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I make a query with Mongoose to get all the items for which my field "reported" contains a positive value?

What I've tried:

```
 Job.find({ reported > 0})
        .limit(20)
        .skip(0)
        .sort({ reported : -1})
        .exec(function(err, jobs){
            callback(null, jobs)
            });
```

Obviously this is not working. Node throw an error because of `{ reported > 0}`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator to perform a query like this:

```
 Job.find({ reported: { $gt: 0 } })
    .limit(20)
    .skip(0)
    .sort({ reported : -1 })
    .exec(function (err, jobs) {
      callback(null, jobs)
    })
```

Keep in mind that the entire query criteria is always a JSON document and something like "reported > 0" is never a valid MongoDB query syntax.